# Sharing an image with nearby share and then displaying it in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-nearby

I am trying to use nearby share in kotlin to send some strings and an image from one device to another but I've been having the same problem for over a month, basically what im trying to do is share some information about a user and then display it in another device, and I have no problem with the strings, but with the image, which I want to display after receiving, I'm getting this error:  `Failed to create image decoder with message 'input was incomplete'`, it's very weird, because sometimes it works -> [this is what i should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXY7z.jpg), others it doesn't -> [failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u9Lx.jpg), and others it just works halfway literally -> [half of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrKtV.png).

The code for receiving the image:

```
val uri = filePayloads[0].asFile()!!.asUri()!!
                    val file = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/${endpointIdUserId.get(endpointId)}-profile-picture-" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpeg"
File(file)

val inp: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
copyStream(inp!!, FileOutputStream(file))

contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)

val user = users.find { it.id == endpointIdUserId.get(endpointId) }

user!!.pfp = file
addPayload(endpointId)

filePayloads.remove(filePayloads[0])
```

The code for displaying the image in a fragment (getting it from a room database):

```
if(currentItem.pfp != null) {
            holder.pfpImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(currentItem.pfp))
        }
```

I would really appreciate any help, thanks guys

Comment: Manage your resources. The Java equivalent of try-with-resources is the Kotlin `use` methd.

Answer (score 0):

You should properly manage and close your resources. Most Streams will flush on close, which makes sure all data is written to their target (the file, in this case):

```
contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { input ->
  FileOutputStream(file).use { output -> 
    copyStream(input, output)
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it's still not working, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't and sometimes it shows only half the image, i tried using Glide and its the same result, i don't know if i can try anything else, it seems weird that there is nothing on the internet on how to receive an image with nearby share and then display it, there is only docs to share it. Let me know if there is anything else i can do.

Comment: @BrunoPiazza Then you'll need to find out what's happening. Attach a debugger and check to see where the problem is: Is the image complete when it comes from the `externalFilesDir`? After being saved to disk? What do you get when you write code to manually download from the URI, instead of passing it to the view? Et cetera.